# how to store commaseperated values in one column ,if user selected morethan one choice from form

Tags: django

I have "user" Model

```
username email phonenumber
```

I want to access all "user" model emails in other model "B" and  make user to select more than one email and store it has commaseperatedvalues

"B" colums are

```
  organization Designation share_knowledge_with
    abc           manager   (here all emails which user selected
                                     to be stored with commaseperated)
```

I tried like this  but not working:

MODEL

```
class B(models.Model):
   organization=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=True)
   emails_for_help = models.TextField(null=True,help_text="select with whom 
   you want to share knowledge")
```

form

```
class Bform(ModelForm): 
 emails_for_help=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
 class Meta:
    model=B
    fields=["organization","emails_for_help"]
```

I tried like this but it is taking null value in "emails_for_help"

Answer (score 0):

`emails_for_help = models.TextField(null=True,help_text="select with whom 
   you want to share knowledge")`

Change this to

`emails_for_help = models.TextField(null=False,help_text="select with whom 
   you want to share knowledge")`

to refuse null values. It will throw an exception you will have to handle, and in that exception you could display a message to the user that no selections aren't permitted.

Comment: actually that is not the issue